# SpringBoot - RequestMappingHandlerMapping Repetition

Tags: java, spring

After migrating to Spring 3.1.5, RequestMapping HandlerMapping occurs repeatedly. I don't think it's a normal situation, can I ask you for your opinion?

Below is the log immediately after API call.

I'm studying individually, but this part bothers me a lot. Please help me ㅜ_ㅠ

```
2023-11-17T05:43:49.145+09:00 DEBUG 67513 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.article.controller.ArticleController#articleList(Pageable)
2023-11-17T05:43:49.145+09:00 DEBUG 67513 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.article.controller.ArticleController#articleList(Pageable)
2023-11-17T05:43:49.145+09:00 DEBUG 67513 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.article.controller.ArticleController#articleList(Pageable)
2023-11-17T05:43:49.146+09:00 DEBUG 67513 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.article.controller.ArticleController#articleList(Pageable)
2023-11-17T05:43:49.146+09:00 DEBUG 67513 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.article.controller.ArticleController#articleList(Pageable)
2023-11-17T05:43:49.146+09:00 DEBUG 67513 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.article.controller.ArticleController#articleList(Pageable)
2023-11-17T05:43:49.146+09:00 DEBUG 67513 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.article.controller.ArticleController#articleList(Pageable)
2023-11-17T05:43:49.146+09:00 DEBUG 67513 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.article.controller.ArticleController#articleList(Pageable)
2023-11-17T05:43:49.147+09:00 DEBUG 67513 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.article.controller.ArticleController#articleList(Pageable)
2023-11-17T05:43:49.147+09:00 DEBUG 67513 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/v1/article?sort=createdAt,desc", parameters={sort:[createdAt,desc]}
2023-11-17T05:43:49.147+09:00 DEBUG 67513 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.article.controller.ArticleController#articleList(Pageable)
```

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        web: debug
    org.springframework.web.servlet: debug
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: trace
```

The logging level is as follows.

Spring security is also being applied, but is it a filter problem?

Comment: Where are you making this request? From the browser? If so I would recommend checking the browser development tools, the network tab. If your back end code is not triggering these calls it is likely the front end application doing so.

Comment: And just in case you don't know what I'm talking about here is an explanation for Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm doing a specific api test with postman. There's no problem with the movement, but it's a personal curiosity. Well, why does this problem happen..

Comment: This are probably the Handler class printing a lot of generic logs. You can always download the source and debug it.